Jetpack Compose Scaffold-content doesn't start below TopAppBar
My onCreate-method looks this way:
setContent {
  CaesarCipherTheme {
    Surface(
      modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
      color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
      Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        topBar = {
          TopAppBar(title = {
            Text(
              text = "Lorem Ipsum Dolor ...",
              textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
              fontSize = 32. sp,
              fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold)
          })
        }) {
        MainScreen()
      }
    }
  }
}

The app appears this way:

The Content starts at the very top and it's upper-part becomes covered by the TopAppBar.
What goes wrong here?
Actually I would expect the content to start below the TopAppBar.
How can the issue become fixed? Besides guessing some padding and apply that.

@Cluster1
You need to use the innerPadding parameter provided by the scaffold to apply padding to the content area inside the scaffold.
You can do something like this:
Scaffold(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            topBar = {}
        )
    { 
    
    //inner padding parameter
    innerPadding ->
    
    //add a modifier to the MainScreen Composable and pass the innerPadding
    MainScreen(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
    
    }

This should help to place the top and bottom bars correctly.

Supplying padding values works
Scaffold(
                        topBar = {}
                        bottomBar = {}
                            
                    ){
                        paddingValues->Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)){
                        NavigationHost(navController = navController)

                    }

